# Entity Framework model from DB2 tables with composite keys

Tags: entity-framework, db2, entity-framework-4.1, foreign-key-relationship

We are testing EF 4.1 against DB2 tables on a Main Frame.

We are now able to generate EF models from DB2 tables and retrieve data :)

When we generate the EF model some relationships are included in the model and some are missing. It appears that the ones that are missing are composite keys.

- Is this a limitation in EF that it is not able to handle composite keys?
- Is it possible add the relationship manually to the model?

Comment: EF can certainly handle composite keys using SQL Server. Try it there and copy what it does?

Comment: "We are now able to generate EF models from DB2 tables and retrieve data :)"

What did you do to generate EF models from DB2 tables. We are trying to this but are just not able to.

Comment: I would also like to know how you connected EF to DB2...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We fixed this by manually editing the edmx files.